# GWT emulation issue (Hibernate Validator)

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5

I'm trying to user super-source to emulate classes GWT has no access to the source code. This ran fine first. But when I use those classes in classes that get validated by Bean Validation (JSR 303), I get an error:
[java] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
...
...
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: somepath/myClass

IMHO this looks like I cannot use Emulations in 'shared' packages but only in the 'client'.

any experiences here?

TIA
ujbi

Answer (score 0):

In `GWT`:

client package compiled  to `javascript`.

Shared package compiles both to `java byte code` and `javascript`.

Most probably while compiling to java code no issues raise.But while compiling to java script you might thrown in to this issue.

```
IMHO  This looks like I cannot use Emulations in 
                                     'shared' packages but only in the 'client'.
```

Yes unfortunately that's **true**.

The code in the shared package must friendly to Compiler. I.e It should emulate.